# Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'typeof ""' has no compatible call signatures React TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to convert three scripts from Javascript to TypeScript. The scripts can be found in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/auser/1d55aa3897f15d17caf21dc39b85b663). I do however have one error left that I can't get rid of. Please note that this is my first React and TypeScript project so I can easily have missed something obvious. I'm using `.tsx` files and TypeScript 2.1.

In the file: `GoogleApiComponent.tsx`

```
import * as cache from './ScriptCache'
...
componentWillMount() {
    this.scriptCache = cache({ <--Error TS2349 here
        google: GoogleApi({
            apiKey: apiKey,
            libraries: libraries
        })
    });
}
```

Gives me this error:

```
Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'typeof "ScriptCache"' has no compatible call signatures.
```

`ScriptCache.tsx` looks like this:

```
let counter = 0;
let scriptMap = new Map();

export const ScriptCache = (function (global: any) {
    return function ScriptCache(scripts: any) {
        const Cache: any = {}
        ...
```

Comment: Please give a full example. This could also be caused by how you `import`/`export` your modules + on what line the error occurs.

Comment: @SebastianSebald You were right, it was an import error! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like you're import is not correct :)

Please try to import it like this `import cache from './ScriptCache'`. If you just used the code from the gist the cache is also exported as default.

If this does not work, try `import { ScriptCache as cache } from './ScriptCache'`. You do not need the `as` syntax. This is just so you don't have to change the variable names.

Comment: Haha just wrote an answer myself but will mark yours as correct. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome! :) Saw it. Was a little bit too late!

Answer (score 2):

Turned out to be an import error as suggested by @Sebastian Sebald.

Wrong:

```
import * as cache from './ScriptCache'
```

Correct:

```
import cache from './ScriptCache'
```

Comment: If you want to better understand the module syntax: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43385452/difference-between-import-as-button-and-import-button/43385719#43385719 :)

Answer (score 0):

Same and slightly different for me:

Wrong:

```
import thing from './dependency'
```

Correct:

```
import { thing } from './dependency'
```